# Multi-column inserted picture out of frame

Tags: beamer, diagrams

I'm trying to add two images side by side in a beamer frame, but one of them is going out of frame.

So, one of my images are a pmatrix. I wrote the following code for an adjacency matrix representation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}

\[\Huge{ 
\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
}
\]

\vspace{15pt}

\huge{Adjacency Matrix (Coordinates are 1-6)}

\end{document}
```

I downloaded the file as pdf from sharelatex. But when I added it, it went out of frame. This is my code for beamer:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg = white}

\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}%

% Swap the definition of \abs* and \norm*, so that \abs
% and \norm resizes the size of the brackets, and the 
% starred version does not.
\makeatletter
\let\oldabs\abs
\def\abs{\@ifstar{\oldabs}{\oldabs*}}
%
\let\oldnorm\norm
\def\norm{\@ifstar{\oldnorm}{\oldnorm*}}
\makeatother


\title[About Beamer]{Graph Representation Techniques}
\author[Author A and Author B]{Tanjim Bin Faruk (1505082) \\ Tanjim Munir (1505083) }
\institute{Bangladesh University of Engineering and Technology}
\date{\today}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \begin{minipage}[b][\paperheight]{\textwidth}
    \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title graphic}\fi
    \vfill%
    \centering % NEW
    \ifx\inserttitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title}\fi
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{subtitle}\fi
    \usebeamertemplate*{title separator}
    \vspace*{10mm}
    \ifx\beamer@shortauthor\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{author}\fi
    \vspace*{20mm} % NEW
    \ifx\insertdate\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{date}\fi
    \ifx\insertinstitute\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{institute}\fi
    \vfill
    \vspace*{1mm}
  \end{minipage}
}

\setbeamertemplate{title}{
%  \raggedright%
    \centering
  \linespread{1.0}%
  \inserttitle%
  \par%
  \vspace*{0.5em}
}


\begin{document}
\metroset{block = fill}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Adjacency Matrix}
    \vspace{1em}
    \only<1>{
    \begin{block}{What is an adjacency matrix?}
    \vspace{0.5em}
     An adjacency matrix is a square matrix used to represent a finite graph.
    \end{block}
    \vspace{0.5em}
    For a graph with $\mathbold{\abs{V}}$ vertices, an adjacency matrix is a $\mathbold{\abs{V} \times \abs{V}}$ matrix.
    \\\vspace{1em}
    If the edge between vertex $\mathbold{i}$ and vertex $\mathbold{j}$ is denoted by $\mathbold{V_{i,j}}$ then there are two possibilities.
    }

    \only<2-3>{
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
        \begin{enumerate}
        \only<2>{
             \item  Unweighted Graph
                \vspace{1em}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Matrix of 0s and 1s where in row $\mathbold{i}$ and column $\mathbold{j}$ is $1$ iff the edge $\mathbold{(i,j)}$ is in the graph
                \end{itemize}

                \[      \Scale[1]{
                        V_{i,j} = \begin{cases}
                                    1 & if ~ edge(i,j) ~ exists \\
                                    0 & otherwise
                                \end{cases}
                        }
                \]
            }
            \addtocounter{enumi}{1}
            \only<3>{
            \item  Weighted Graph
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Edge weight is placed in $\mathbold{V_{i,j}}$ entry if there is an edge and a special value (perhaps \textit{\textbf{null}}) to indicate the absence of an edge. 
                \end{itemize}

                \[
                    V_{i,j} = \begin{cases}
                                W_{i,j} & if ~ edge(i,j) ~ exists \\
                                null & otherwise 
                            \end{cases}
                \]
            }
        \end{enumerate}
    }
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \only<4>{
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includesvg[scale = 0.3]{Figures/unweightedgraph.svg}
        \label{fig:my_label}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{Figures/temp.pdf}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{fig:my_label}
    \end{figure}
    }
    \end{multicols}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And I'm talking about this particular segment of my code:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \only<4>{
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includesvg[scale = 0.3]{Figures/unweightedgraph.svg}
        \label{fig:my_label}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{Figures/temp.pdf}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{fig:my_label}
    \end{figure}
    }
    \end{multicols}
```

Currently the output looks like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you check the bounding box of the .svg file?

Comment: Is it just that you created the matrix from `\documentclass{article}` and you would be better of if you remove the border by using `\documentclass{standalone}` instead?

Comment: Link of the svg file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xv1tmpD2rAxNvY9hlSEcN3jPRwv_WQaD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For future questions, please read [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `\Huge` and `\huge` to produce your matrix PDF image but then included it with `scale = 0.5`. Why not just type your `pmatrix` directly into your slide?

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \only<4>{
    \centering
    \includesvg[scale = 0.3]{Figures/unweightedgraph.svg}

    \[
    \begin{pmatrix}
      2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
      1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
      0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
      1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \]
    Adjacency Matrix (Coordinates are 1-6)
  }
\end{multicols}
```

Answer (score 5):

- I would not use `multicols` with beamer - beamer has its own mechanism for columns.
- you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer
- Personally I find it much easier to just specify the width of images instead of having to experiment to find a suitable scaling factor.
- don't use the same lable multiple times
- figures are automatically centred in beamer, no need for `\centering`

---

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}


\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usecolortheme{spruce}

%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}



\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[t]{Adjacency Matrix}

    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \includesvg[width=\textwidth]{unweightedgraph.svg}
            \label{fig:my_label}
        \end{figure}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \label{fig:my_labela}
        \end{figure}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

mostly not related to your problem, however i can't resit to show how i would prepare this frame and avoid to your problem(s):

- instead use of svg image i would drawn own with `tikz` (showed graph are relatively simple and not require big effort to code it)
- matrix i would  write and not insert its image (i'm convinced, that this is simpler and require less work)

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  \usetheme{metropolis}
  \usecolortheme{spruce}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{Adjacency Matrix}

  \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style = {circle, draw=blue!70!black, fill=cyan!30},
      node distance = 3mm and 5mm,
              thick
                      ]
  \node (s1) {1};
  \node (s2) [above left=of s1]   {2};
  \node (s3) [above=of s2]        {3};
  \node (s4) [right=of s3]        {4};
  \node (s5) [above right=of s1]  {5};
  \node (s6) [above right=of s4]  {6};
  \draw   (s1) to [loop right, looseness=12] (s1)
          (s1) -- (s2) -- (s3) -- (s4) -- (s5) -- (s1)
          (s2) -- (s5)
          (s4) -- (s6);
  \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
      \[\setlength\arraycolsep{9pt}
      \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
      \end{pmatrix}
      \]
      \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  \end{frame}

  \end{document}
  ```

[image]